# Printf seems to be overwriting pointer

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

After i call printf for the first time to print out the duplicate it then changes it's mammals pointer to giberish. So when it prints inside the second loop the first mammal comes out fine but then the next in the list is lost. Then every time it exits that loop the next duplicate in the list is lost.

```
void print_list3() {
Duplicate *next=head3.duppointer;
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<list_length3;i++) {
    printf("%c %d %f %f\n",next->species,next->number_of,next->location.lat,next->location.lng);
    Mammal mam;
    mam=*next->mampointer;
    for(j=0;j<next->number_of;j++) {
        printf("   %f %f %s\n",mam.location.lat,mam.location.lng,mam.observer.id);
        if (mam.pointer!=NULL) {
            mam=*mam.pointer;
        }
    }
    if (next!=NULL) {
        next=next->duppointer;
    }
}
```

}

Edit: Decided to put all of my code in here, maybe it'll be easier for you guys to find the bug. The problem is with function 2.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "navigation.h"
#include "Mainheader.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <math.h>

int list_length1=0;
int list_length2=0;
int list_length3=0;
Observer head1;
Mammal head2;
Duplicate head3;
/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int choice=0;
    run_menu();
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    while(choice<1 || choice>4) {
        printf("Invalid choice\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
    }
    if(choice==1) {
        function1();
    }
    else if(choice==2) {
        function2();
    }
    else if(choice==3) {
        function3();
    }
    else if(choice==4) {
        printf("Exiting!");
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void run_menu() {
    printf("1 - Display cetacean Mammals          fn1\n"
           "2 - Display without duplicates        fn2\n"
           "3 - Display Pods without duplicates   fn3\n"
           "4 - Exit\n");
}

void function1(){
    int i=0;
    get_directories();
    Mammal *next;
    next=head2.pointer;
    for(i=0;i<list_length2;i++) {
        location_calculator(next);
        if (next!=NULL) {
            next=next->pointer;
        }
    }   
    print_reallist();
}
void function2(){
    int i=0;
    get_directories();
    Mammal *next;
    next=head2.pointer;
    for(i=0;i<list_length2;i++) {
        location_calculator(next);
        if (next!=NULL) {
            next=next->pointer;
        }
    }
    remove_duplicates();
    print_list3();
}
void function3(){

}
char get_directories() {
    char file1[256];
    char file2[256];
    char obsid[5];
    TD td;
    FILE *file_no1;
    FILE *file_no2;
    Observer* obs=malloc(sizeof(*obs));
    Mammal* mam=malloc(sizeof(*mam));
    //printf("Please Enter Observer File Path: ");
    //scanf("%s",&file1);
    strcpy(file1,"/ceri/homes1/j/jsc12/CS237/Assignment/cetaceans/data/observers_2.txt");
    file_no1=fopen(file1, "r");
    fscanf(file_no1,"%d%d%d%d%d%d",&td.day,&td.month,&td.year,&td.hour,&td.minute,&td.second);
    while(fscanf(file_no1,"%s%lf%lf",obs->id,&obs->location.lat,&obs->location.lng)==3) {
        obs->timedate=td;
        Observer *new;
        new=create_observer(obs->id,obs->location,obs->timedate);
        add_observer(new);
    }
    fclose(file_no1);
    //printf("Please Enter Sighting File Path: ");
    //scanf("%s",&file2);
    strcpy(file2,"/ceri/homes1/j/jsc12/CS237/Assignment/cetaceans/data/sightings_2.txt");
    file_no2=fopen(file2, "r");
    while(fscanf(file_no2,"%4s %c %lf%lf",&obsid,&mam->species,&mam->bearing,&mam->range)==4) {
        Observer* obs2=find_observer(obsid);
        mam->observer=*obs2;
        Mammal *new;
        new=create_mammal(mam->observer,mam->species,mam->bearing,mam->range);
        add_mammal(new);
    }
    fclose(file_no2);
}
Mammal* create_mammal (Observer obs,char spec,double bear,double ran){
    Mammal* b=malloc(sizeof *b);
    b->observer=obs;
    b->species=spec;
    b->bearing=bear;
    b->range=ran;
    b->pointer=NULL;

    return b;
}
void add_mammal (Mammal *n){
    n->pointer=head2.pointer;
    head2.pointer=n;
    list_length2++;
}
Duplicate* create_duplicate (Duplicate* d){
    Mammal mam;
    int i;
    location average;
    average.lat=0;
    average.lng=0;
    mam=*d->mampointer;
    Duplicate* b;
    b=malloc(sizeof *b);
    b->species=d->mampointer->species;
    b->number_of=d->number_of;
    for(i=0;i<d->number_of;i++) {
        average.lat+=mam.location.lat;
        average.lng+=mam.location.lng;
        if (mam.pointer!=NULL) {
            mam=*mam.pointer;
        }
    }
    average.lat/=d->number_of;
    average.lng/=d->number_of;
    b->location=average;
    b->mampointer=d->mampointer;
    b->duppointer=NULL;

    return b;
}
void add_duplicate (Duplicate *n){
    n->duppointer=head3.duppointer;
    head3.duppointer=n;
    list_length3++;
}
Observer* create_observer (char id[5],location locat,TD timdat){
    Observer* b=malloc(sizeof *b);
    strcpy(b->id,id);
    b->location=locat;
    b->timedate=timdat;
    b->pointer=NULL;
    return b;
}
void add_observer (Observer *n){
    n->pointer=head1.pointer;
    head1.pointer=n;
    list_length1++;
}
Observer* find_observer(char id[5]) {
    Observer *next=head1.pointer;
    int i=0;
    while(i<list_length1) {
        if(strcmp(id,next->id)==0) {
            return(next);
        }
        next=next->pointer;
        i++;
    }
}

void location_calculator(Mammal* m) {
    double obslat=m->observer.location.lat;
    double obslng=m->observer.location.lng;
    double rbear=(m->bearing*M_PI)/180;
    m->location.lat=obslat+(m->range*cos(rbear))/60;
    m->location.lng=obslng+(m->range*sin(rbear)/cos((obslat*M_PI)/180))/60;
}
void print_reallist() {
    Mammal *next=head2.pointer;
    int i;
    printf("|==========|==========|==========|==========|\n");
    printf("|%-10s|%-10s|%-10s|%-10s|\n","Longitude","Latitude","Species","Observer");
    printf("|==========|==========|==========|==========|\n");
    for(i=0;i<list_length2;i++) {
        if (next->species=='P') {
            printf("|%-10lf|%-10lf|%-10s|%-10s|\n",next->location.lat,next->location.lng,"Porpoise",next->observer.id);
            if (next!=NULL) {
                next=next->pointer;
            } 
        }
        else {
            printf("|%-10lf|%-10lf|%-10s|%-10s|\n",next->location.lat,next->location.lng,"Dolphin",next->observer.id);
            if (next!=NULL) {
                next=next->pointer;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("|==========|==========|==========|==========|\n");
}
void remove_duplicates() {
    int i,j;
    double distance;
    Mammal *next=head2.pointer;
    for(i=0;i<list_length2-1;i++) {
        Mammal *check=next->pointer;
        Duplicate d;
        d.mampointer=NULL;
        d.number_of=0;
        for(j=0;j<(list_length2-i)-1;j++) {
            distance=great_circle(next->location, check->location);
            if(distance<=0.02 && next->species==check->species) {
                Mammal a=*next;
                Mammal b=*check;
                a.pointer=d.mampointer;
                d.mampointer=&a;
                b.pointer=d.mampointer;
                d.mampointer=&b;
                d.number_of++;
                d.number_of++;
            }
            printf("%f\n",distance);
            if (check!=NULL) {
                check=check->pointer;
            } 
        }
        if(d.mampointer!=NULL) {
            add_duplicate(create_duplicate(&d));
        }
        if (next!=NULL) {
            next=next->pointer;
        } 
    }
}
void print_list3() {
    Duplicate *next=head3.duppointer;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<list_length3;i++) {
        printf("%c %d %f %f\n",next->species,next->number_of,next->location.lat,next->location.lng);
        Mammal mam;
        mam=*next->mampointer;
        for(j=0;j<next->number_of;j++) {
            printf("   %f %f %s\n",mam.location.lat,mam.location.lng,mam.observer.id);
            if (mam.pointer!=NULL) {
                mam=*mam.pointer;
            }
        }
        if (next!=NULL) {
            next=next->duppointer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Printf is not causing that problem unless memory corruption has caused the stdin global pointer to get corrupted.  Of course, that's also assuming no other tricks - like someone replacing printf with an alternative.

Comment: There is no much details to say definitely, but the most common way the `printf()` may alter the data is that you using local variable the wrong way.  For example, if you return the pointer to the local variable, the data the pointer point to may be overwritten by any next function call.

Comment: One possibility is that the pointer you are passing to `printf()` is a pointer to a local variable in a function that has since terminated, so the space it points at is reused.  That is, some function you called returned a pointer, and then you pass that pointer to `printf()`.  Since `printf()` reuses the space, the value changes when you call `printf()`.

Comment: the pointers passed to print are local pointers to a global variable so I'm pretty sure that wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @Jim006Jam How do you allocate memory for your structures and for pointers inside structures?

Comment: In the functions `create_Observer()`,`create_mammal()`and `create_duplicate()`.

Comment: @Jim006Jam probably
    void remove_duplicates() {
    ...
    Mammal a=*next;
    ...
    d.mampointer=&a;

`Mama a=*next;` should be memcpy to a local variable and `d.mampointer=&a;` saves it's pointer.

Comment: I tried using malloc, `Duplicate *d=malloc(sizeof(d))` and this was my output.
`33.892317
9.455547
9.454818
25.756796
25.756453
32.580635
32.580642
*** Error in `/ceri/homes1/j/jsc12/.netbeans/remote/central.aber.ac.uk/james-pc-Windows-x86_64/Z/NetBeansProjects/Mammals/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/mammals': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000001f100e0 ***`

Comment: `char get_directories()` does not return a value.

Comment: that part of the code works fine but good spot :)

Comment: [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) is your friend

Comment: Your malloc for Duplicate is only malloc'ing 4 bytes, I.E. a pointer.  Probably not what you want.  suggest: Duplicate *d=malloc(sizeof(Duplicate) );

Comment: there are several points in the code where a memory allocation is performed using malloc() however: 1) the returned value from malloc() is not being checked to assure the operation was successful. 2) all that allocated memory is not being passed to free(), so the program has massive memory leaks.

Comment: this line: int main(int argc, char** argv) { will cause the compiler to raise two warning messages about unused parameters.  suggest use: int main()

Comment: this line: scanf("%d",&choice); (in main()) has a few problems, mostly because the returned value from scanf is not being checked to assure the operation was successful.  Also, the following lines would be much better (and more clearly) written as a switch statement, where the 'default' case would catch invalid input from the user.

Comment: the functions: function1, function2, function3 are really bad functions names.  1) they are very similar in spelling 2) they give no meaningful indication as to what the function does.  Suggest you give them meaningful names that contain a action verb and indicate what the function performs.

Comment: meaningful names are VERY important for the understandability of the code.  this line: next=head2.pointer; has two problems: 1) there is no indication of what head2 is all about.  2) the name 'head2' is about mammals, so a MUCH better name would be MammalsListHead and the indicated line is skipping the contents of the head2 instance, so head2 would be much better off as Mammals *MammalsListHead, so it points to the first actual entry in the list of mammals.  Also, std practice is to use 'next' and 'prev' for field names in a linked list of structs, not some (unexpected) name like 'pointer'

Comment: You didn't post all of your code - "navigation.h" and "Mainheader.h" are missing.

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems for the first sight.

It is C, but would be better to avoid name 'new'. Identifier 'location' is a struct name and variable name too. Functions char get_directories() and Observer * find_observer() do not always return.

There are five malloc() but no free() calls.

I am afraid that such function declarations will not guarantee string size, a simple pointer is passed:

```
Observer * create_observer ( char id[5], ..
```

Return value of fscanf is not checked. 6 is expected but returns actually 1, because no proper format provided. Perhaps try "%2d%2d%2d%2d%2d%2d"!

```
fscanf(file_no1,"%d%d%d%d%d%d",&td.day,&td.month,&td.year,&td.hour,&td.minute,&td.second);
```

Same problem with observer lines. How should fscanf know where the end of string and/or double is? Try for instance "%4s %lf %lf"!

```
while(fscanf(file_no1,"%s%lf%lf",obs->id,&obs->location.lat,&obs->location.lng)==3) {
```

String obsid is not scanned properly at this point (remove address operator &):

```
while(fscanf(file_no2,"%4s %c %lf%lf",&obsid,&mam->species,&mam->bearing,&mam->range)==4) {
```

Function find_observer() would correctly return NULL if obsid not found. Pointer should not be used in this case, so please check obs2 first:

```
Observer* obs2=find_observer(obsid);
mam->observer=*obs2;
```

Could you provide code parts with example input to reproduce problem and resolve issue? I had to reverse engineer even to get following structures to compile at all:

```
struct Loc { double lat; double lng; };
struct TD { int year; int month; int day;  int hour; int minute; int second; };
struct Observer { char id[1024]; Loc location; TD timedate; Observer * pointer; };
struct Mammal { char species; double bearing; double range; Observer observer; Mammal * pointer; Loc location; };
struct Duplicate { Mammal * mampointer; int number_of; char species; Loc location; Duplicate * duppointer; };
```

And great_circle( Loc, Loc ) function is missing either. Replaced by planar distance calculation instead of supposed spheric:

```
double great_circle( Loc p0, Loc p1 ) { return pow( ( p0.lat - p1.lat ), 2.0 ) + pow( ( p0.lng - p1.lng ), 2.0 ); }
```

Without trying duplicates it runs fine for me after fixing errors above.